# conflict of namespace with use statement in phalcon class

Tags: class, namespaces

I'm very confuse with conflict between namespace that registered in index.php with class implementing associated namespace.
In index.php :

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
        'Akademik\Controllers' => __DIR__ . $config->application->controllersDir,
        'Akademik\Plugins' => __DIR__ . $config->application->pluginsDir,
        'Akademik\Library' => __DIR__ . $config->application->libraryDir,
        'Akademik\Models' => __DIR__ . $config->application->modelsDir,
))->register();
```

In my class :

```
namespace Akademik\Plugins;

use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin;
use Phalcon\Events\Event;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
use Phalcon\Acl;



class Security extends Plugin
{

   public function __construct($dependencyInjector)
   {
    $this->_dependencyInjector = $dependencyInjector;
   }

   public function getAcl()
   {
      if (!isset($this->persistent->acl)) {

        $acl = new Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory();
```

When I fire up index.php, I've got :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Akademik\Plugins\Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory' not found in C:\nginx\html\app\plugins\Security.php on line 27
```

I'm very new to phalcon, also namespaces, any help will be appreciated. Tks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the correct namespace escape, and the Adapter is not set under the `use` statement which is why it is placed below the `Akademik\Plugins\` namespace.

Here are two ways to fix it.

#### Easiest Option

```
// Go to This line 
$acl = new Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory();
```

So you have to either change it to this, to add to the global namespace:

```
// Add an Escape "\" before Phalcon
$acl = new \Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory();
```

#### Other Option

Otherwise, you can do a use statement like that the top:

```
// Add this to the top (Alias is optional, otherwise it's new Memory())
use Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory as AclMemory;

... 

// Create the instance this way
$acl = new AclMemory();
```

Hope that helps.